# I can not load SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Management Tool, and it said all components are installed successfully.

But when I try to start SQL Server Management Studio, it just show like in the screenshot shown below. Did I miss something?

[image]

These are my SQL Server related components:

[image]

Comment: restart Server and check again

Comment: Tried, also reinstall, did not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed.**

I have tried to uninstall & install application, restart computer, but they did not work for me. After several hours google search, below solution works for me, hope it will help others who face the same problem.

**Solution:** right click on  "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio", click "Properties", then "run compatibility troubleshooter" on "Compatibility" tab. After detecting issue, choose"try recommended setting".

[image]

Comment: Interesting that you need to do this for SQL Server 2016 on Windows 10 / Server 2016! As long as it works, I guess! Could you include what the changed compatibility settings are, if any? It might help those who come across the same issue later on.

Comment: Hi Hop, I can not see the detail of change compatibility setting, just one picture like i add in  my answer.

Comment: No worries then, was just a suggestion :)